# What is a "Web Application"?

Tags: android, google-app-engine

[Here](http://code.google.com/appengine/), Google is talking about "web apps". Is a "web app" just an Android app that is connected to the web? Android app you need internet access for?

Comment: +1 because I could not find a duplicate here. I suppose Stackoverflow should have one question with this basic definition. May it will be this one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Web app" is simply a broad term that can be used to refer to any web based/hosted site or service that involves a significant amount of user interaction, user generated content, or provides a "rich" user experience or a service API for third-parties to integrate with.  A web app interface will "run" inside of a web browser, while typically all of the state handling and business logic will be handled by a backing server.

Google App Engine exists to provide a platform for implementing the "backing server" component of a web app (as well as basic hosting for the static resources needed by the app).

The concept of a web app really has nothing to do directly with Android apps.  However, an Android app may (and many Android apps commonly do) communicate with a web app to provide various features or services within the app (think weather, Facebook integration, etc.).  And in certain cases it is possible to implement a "quick and dirty" Android app by simply pointing a `WebView` at an existing web app's URL.  In such a case that Android app's `WebView` becomes the "browser" that the web app's UI runs in.

Answer (score 2):

Web app traditionally means a browser-based UI.

Google Web Apps was introduced in 2008, before the rise of the iPhone and Android.  I would say those are a later addition to the definition.

If the client is using HTTP as its communication protocol with back-end services, I would call it a "web app", regardless of what the client hardware is.

Comment: Note that this definition includes both the traditional server-rendered HTML pages (old-school CGI, PHP, JSP, ASP) as well as the modern Javascript-based screens that talk to presentation-independent web services. So I'd say the cut is between browser-based versus native app (Visual Basic forms, iPhone app, Android app). The Internet-connected Android app in the question would then not be a web-app.